# How to deserialise xml attribute value to C# object attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization, wikipedia-api

My Xml looks like following:

```
  <SearchSuggestion xmlns="http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2" version="2.0">
  <Query xml:space="preserve">middle ages</Query>
  <Section>

    <Item>
      <Text xml:space="preserve">Middle Ages</Text>
      <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages</Url>
      <Description xml:space="preserve">
In the history of Europe, the Middle Ages or medieval period lasted from the 5th to the 15th century. It began with the fall of the Western Roman Empire and merged into the Renaissance and the Age of Discovery.
</Description>
      <Image source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0a/JuengeresMathildenkreuz.jpg/35px-JuengeresMathildenkreuz.jpg" width="35" height="50"/>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Text xml:space="preserve">Middle Ages in film</Text>
      <Url xml:space="preserve">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages_in_film</Url>
      <Description xml:space="preserve">
Medieval films imagine and portray the Middle Ages through the visual, audio and thematic forms of cinema.
</Description>
      <Image source="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/39/Fairbanks_Robin_Hood_standing_by_wall_w_sword.jpg/40px-Fairbanks_Robin_Hood_standing_by_wall_w_sword.jpg" width="40" height="50"/>
    </Item>

  </Section>
</SearchSuggestion>
```

My Object looks as following:

```
[XmlRoot("SearchSuggestion", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class SearchItem
{

    [XmlElement("Query")]
    public string query { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Section")]
    public Section section { get; set; }

}
public class Section
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
}
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("source")]
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

}

I want to store "source" attribute Url but after running program I keep getting an empty source string in infoResult array.
My Controller looks as following:

```
        string wikiResponse; //raw response from REST endpoint
        SearchItem wikiXmlResponse = null; //Deserialized response


        wikiResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(queryUri);
        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(wikiResponse);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {

              var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SearchItem));
              wikiXmlResponse (SearchItem)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
        Items [] infoResult = wikiXmlResponse.section.items;
```

Comment: To prevent confusion, you should rename the type "Items" to "Item" and your property "Section.Item" to "Section.Items".

Comment: oh Yea, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
public class Image
{
    [XmlAttribute("source")]
    public string source { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Properties should be something like below, comparing your XML.
You can convert your XML code to CSharp classes online @ http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Query
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Text", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Text
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Url", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Url
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Description", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Description
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "space", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
    public string Space { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Image", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Image
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "width")]
    public string Width { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "height")]
    public string Height { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Text", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Text Text { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Url", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Url Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Image", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Section", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class Section
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Item", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public List<Items> Item { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SearchSuggestion", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
public class SearchItem
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Query", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Query Query { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Section", Namespace = "http://opensearch.org/searchsuggest2")]
    public Section Section { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```